# How to pass null in body to endpoint within asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following action within an asp.net core 3.1 controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("example")]
public class MyExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("{id}/value")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string id, [FromBody] int? value)
      => Task.FromResult(Ok());
}
```

This works fine if I post a body value of int (for example: `1`, `2`, etc...)

However, I can't find a way to get a `null` value passed in.

If I pass in an empty body or `null` body I get a status code of 400 returned with a validation message of `A non-empty request body is required.` returned.

I've also tried to change the `value` parameter to be an optional argument with a default value of `null`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string id, [FromBody] int? value = null)
```

How do I pass in null to this action?

Comment: is this within a `[ApiController]` adorned controller?

Comment: Yep, the controller is annotated with a `[ApiController]` attribute.

Comment: That is the cause of the problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#automatic-http-400-responses

Comment: @Nkosi but the ModelState should be valid, If I do the same in a normal class with a nullable property that is valid?

Comment: To test that theory, remove the `[ApiController]` attribute and try the same request to see if we can rule that out as the cause.

Comment: @Nkosi just removed the attribute and it's working... The Model state says it's invalid with `"A non-empty request body is required."`

Comment: Right. Yes we know it is invalid but it looks like the attribute adds the additional feature of short-circuiting the request. Causing the issue experienced.

Comment: To me this model is not invalid though, why is it invalid when there is no [Required] attribute?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally figured this out, big thanks to @Nkosi and @KirkLarkin helping fault find this.

Within the `Startup.cs`  when configuring the controllers into the container we just need to alter the default mvc options to `AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(x => x.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding = true);
}
```

This way we can pass in `null` into the body of the post and it works perfectly fine. It also still applies the normal model validation via the attributes without having to check the ModelState manually:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string id,
        [FromBody][Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value bigger than 1")]
        int? value = null)
```

Answer (score 6):

Reference [Automatic HTTP 400 responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#automatic-http-400-responses)

> The `[ApiController]` attribute makes model validation errors automatically trigger an HTTP 400 response

This would explain the returned response.

Remove the `[ApiController]` to allow the invalid request to still make it to the controller action and also if the additional features of having that attribute is not critical to the current controller.

It would however require that the desired featured be applied manually

```
[Route("example")]
public class MyExampleController : ControllerBase {
    [HttpPost("{id}/value")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string id, [FromBody] int? value) {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {

            //...

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        //...

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: This kinda fixes it, but it's not an invalid model as it doesn't have the [Required] attribute on the method argument. It's more of a workaround as all the rest of my actions will inside this controller will need to manually check the model state...

Comment: @KevinSmith It is seen as invalid by the framework because the action parameter explicitly **requires** it `[FromBody]`

Comment: @KevinSmith If you make the parameter optional and remove the `[FromBody]`, see if that gives you the desired behavior.

Comment: Have a look at [`AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.allowemptyinputinbodymodelbinding?view=aspnetcore-3.1). That's a _global_ setting though.

Comment: @KirkLarkin perfect. Totally missed that. Much appreciated.

Comment: @KirkLarkin does that apply with `ApiController` present? Because that would totally solve the OPs issue

Comment: You can also configure `ApiBehaviorOptions` to customise the behavior of `ApiControllerAttribute`, rather than remove the attribute

Answer (score 0):

It seems it has something to do with the way a single value is conducted through JSON. It expects a value and the null just simply creates an empty request body. You should consider defining a class like this

```
    public class MyInt{
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public bool IsNull { get; set; }
    }

    [ApiController]
    [Route("example")]
    public class MyExampleController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("{id}/value")]
        public IActionResult Post(string id, [FromBody]MyInt value)
        {
            if(value.IsNull){

            }
            else{

            }
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

In other words when you POST you post not just use a default value. You could do that the other way like this

```
[HttpPost("{id}/value")]
public IActionResult Post(string id, [FromBody]int value)...
[HttpGet("{id}/value")]
public IActionResult Get(string id)...//use the default value here
```